# ODE Power Series Solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following ODE: $y''+t^3y'+3t^2y = 0$, with $y(0) =1, y'(0) = -1$

This is my attempt so far:
Following the power series solution approach, let $y = \sum_{i=0}^n a_nt^n$
then $y'' = \sum_{i=0}^nn(n-1)a_nt^{n-2} = \sum_{i=-4}^n (n+4)(n+3)a_{n+4}t^{n+2} = 2a_2 +6a_3+ \sum_{i=0}^n (n+4)(n+3)a_{n+4}t^{n+2} $

So, plugging in the original ODE, we have $2a_2 + 6a_3t + \sum_{i=0}^n (n+4)(n+3)a_{n+4}t^{n+2} + \sum_{i=0}^nna_nt^{n+2} + 3\sum_{i=0}^na_nt^{n+2} = 0 $.
Therefore, we have $2a_2 = 0, 6a_3 = 0, and (n+4)(n+3)a_{n+4}+(n+3)a_n = 0$
And we have the following recurrent relation: $a_{n+4} = \frac{-a_n}{n+4}$

Using $ y'(0) = - 1$, we have $a_1 = -1 => a_5 = \frac{1}{5}, a_9 = \frac{1}{9} \frac{1}{5} (-1)  $, so I can write this solution as $a_{4n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{5.9.13...(4n+1)}t^{4n+1} $

However, I come up with a problem while using the other initial condition $y(0) = 1$ =>  $a_0 = 1$ => $a_4 = \frac{-1}{4}, a_9 = \frac{1}{8} \frac{1}{4} $

I try to write this solution as $a_{4n} = \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^{n}}{4.8.12...(4n)}t^{4n} $, but I don't know if it works because if $n = 0$, the denominator will be $0$.
So what can I do here? Do I just leave out $n = 0$ and write the solution as $1 + \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{n}}{4.8.12...(4n)}t^{4n}$ ?

Also, as a side question, is there a way that I can verify that my power series solution is correct? Thank you!

Comment: $4\cdot8\cdots4n=4^nn!$

Comment: Thank you! my other solution is still correct, right?

Comment: I don't know.  I haven't checked any of your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

*Also, as a side question, is there a way that I can verify that my power series solution is correct? Thank you!*

---

$$y''+t^3y'+3t^2y = 0$$
$$y''+(t^3y)' = 0$$
$$y'+t^3y = C_1$$
$$(e^{t^4/4}y)' = C_1e^{t^4/4}$$
$$e^{t^4/4}y = C_1 \int e^{t^4/4}dt+C_2$$
$$y = C_1e^{-t^4/4} \int e^{t^4/4}dt+C_2e^{-t^4/4}$$
You can easily check at least one of your series solution. Note that:
$$e^t=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac {t^n}{n!}$$
$$y_2(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n\dfrac {t^{4n}}{4^nn!}$$
Note that  the denominator is never zero since you have at the denominator $4^nn!$ and for $n=0$ you get $4^00!=1$

Comment: Thank you, this helps me verify $\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^{n}}{4^n n!}t^{4n}$ is a solution. Can this help me verify the other solution? And is there a general way to verify power series solution?

Comment: The other solution is not easy to integrate with elementary functions...So I don't know if there is a way to check easily your second solution @sucksatmath apart from putting it in the differential equation and differentiate.